# Rails Spree bundle install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, spree

I am following the [github instructions](https://github.com/spree/spree) and on command bundle install I have error:

```
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree.git
Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git
Fetching git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...Killed
```

Whithout this gems all other installed

```
gem "spree", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree"
gem "spree_gateway", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_gateway"
gem "spree_auth_devise", :git => "git://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise"
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'g
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'spree', '3.0.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

Comment: Spree isn't being maintained anymore, use [Solidus](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus) instead

Comment: Spree is still being maintained https://github.com/spree/spree